# ¿Cómo consulto una API que genera un Token con código de Power Query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Tengo que generar un token a través de una API con autorización OAuth2. La forma de invocar esa API con Power Shell es esta, y me funciona correctamente:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Headers @{ ContentType='application/json' } -Body @{ client_id="****"; client_secret="****"; grant_type="***" } -Uri $URL | ConvertTo-Json
```

Al ejecutar este comando de Power Shell me devuelve perfectamente el Token, además de otros dos parámetros más en formato JSON.

Necesito replicar esa misma llamada con código de M Query en Power BI. Lo que tengo es esto:

```
let
url="****",
hdr=[
    #"Content-Type"="application/json",
    Method="POST"
],
body=Text.ToBinary("{
    ""client_id"":""****"",
    ""client_secret"":""****"",
    ""grant_type"":""****""
    }"),
data=Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,[
    Headers=hdr,
    Content=body
]))
 in
   data
```

Pero cuando ejecuto este código siempre me devuelve Error 400.

> DataSource.Error: Web.Contents no pudo obtener el contenido de '****' (400): Bad Request.

Al tratar de hacer la llamada desde Postman, también obtengo el mismo error. Es evidente que algo hago mal, pero no lo tengo muy claro, ya que son exactamente los mismos parámetros que paso en el comando de PowerShell.

Lo que me devuelve Postman es este JSON:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request"
}
```

He probado un código parecido con una API de jsonplaceholder, haciendo una petición POST y pasándole parámetros en Power Query, y obtuve un resultado correcto. Algún parámetro o configuración se me escapa con la otra API tanto en Postman como en P.Query.

¿Alguien me sabría decir qué estoy haciendo mal para que en PowerShell funcione y ni en Postman ni en M Query lo haga? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo logré. Por si a alguien se le presenta mi mismo problema, así lo solucioné. Os dejo el código.

```
let
url="****",
hdr=[
    #"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    Method="POST"
],
body=Text.ToBinary("client_id=****&client_secret=****&grant_type=****"),
data=Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,[
    Headers=hdr,
    Content=body
]))[access_token]
in
    data
```